# Can't find/see other network user in file sharing

Tags: file-sharing

My Network have all other users available/shown.
However, when I am trying to share folder to someone, I cannot find/search \their network name.
Please help.

- Function Discovery Provider Host
- Function Discovery Resource Publication
- SSDP Discovery
- UPnP Device Host

These have been set to Automatic.
Enable SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support already.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the computer part of an Active Directory domain? Can you select anything else besides your own computer under "Location..."?

Comment: @user1686 what do you mean by Active Directory domain? Set user in cmd > all my computer name. System Properties, WORKGROUP in workgroup.
Only my PC name in the "Locations...". In fact, I tried to type \\network name on it, but windows unable to find the name.

Answer (score 1):

Your other workgroup computers are not on the list because Windows doesn't support sharing something to "all users from computer X" – sharing is strictly based on *user* accounts.

But user accounts are not shared across a workgroup, either – each computer has its own accounts (with different security IDs), and when someone connects to your computer they have to log in to a corresponding account on *your* machine.

So in order to share something to user Y, you must first create a *local* account named "Y" and give its password to the person (or alternatively make your local account have the same password as theirs). It doesn't matter which computer that user connects from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share a folder with sb. on your LAN please right click on the folder and find `Properties`.

Find the `Sharing` tab on the pop-up conv. panel.

Press `Advanced sharing` button and check `Share this folder`. Press `Permissions` button and Allow Full control to Everyone.

[image]

Because remote user is not known in your system you need to create a user for this purpose and need to share the credential with your counterpart.

1.) Run `compmgmt.msc` from `Start menu` and navigate yourself to `Local Users and Groups`.

2.) Create a user with password and send it your counterpart.

3.) If he\she tries to open the folder Windows Authentication panel pops up where the account will be able to log on and browse the folder.

*.) *If you need to grant write privilege to this user please navigate back under the folder properties and find the security tab. Change the privilege of the USER group.*

** If answer help please don't forget to mark as accepted answer. Thx.